# Problems with Lyx and bigints

Tags: packages, lyx, installing

I found online that a good package to write big integrals is bigints. Despite installing it, using TexLive Shell, Lyx doesn't show any changes in the commands (but if I press "latex info" it shows up in latex styles section). The same happened when I tried to install relsize. Instead, I could download and install mhchem without problems, doing the exact same procedure. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It is not very clear what the problem is. What shall "Lyx doesn't show any changes in the commands" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LyX provides graphical support for most of the common used packages, but, since LaTeX has an immense amount of packages, it is impractical to have support for all of them.

Luckily, LyX provides a bunch of ways to add a graphical support for new layouts and math macros or to change an existing one.

First of all, to use `bigints` package, go to <kbd>Document</kbd>-><kbd>Settings</kbd>-><kbd>LaTeX Preamble</kbd>, write in the text block `\usepackage{bifints}` and then press <kbd>Apply</kbd>. The go to <kbd>Document</kbd>-><kbd>Settings</kbd>-><kbd>Math Options</kbd> and change the radio button of the `esint` package to do not load (since this package clashes with `bigints`).

Now, lets say you want to use the command `\bigint`, You can simply write inside a math inset `\bigint`, but LyX will present is as raw text inside the formula, which might not desirable. To add graphical support for that command, go to <kbd>Insert</kbd>-><kbd>Math</kbd>-><kbd>Macro</kbd>, give a name to the new macro you want to create (the should not be occupied, unless you want to change an existing command), say `\myint`, in the TeX code write `\bigint` and in the LyX part add a symbol that LyX already support, say `(B)\int`. In the end You should end up with something of the following form

[image]

Now, every time you will write in math inset `\myint` you will see in LyX the LyX part of the macro, and in the PDF you will get the outcome of `\bigint`.

For more information about math macros in LyX read section 22 of LyX's math guide which can be found at <kbd>Help</kbd>-><kbd>Math</kbd>.

Here is a LyX file that demonstrate the usage of such macro (to open it with LyX, copy the code to a text file and change the extension to .lyx):

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{bigints}
\end_preamble
\options no-math
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype true
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 1
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 12
\spacing onehalf
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 0
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset FormulaMacro
\newcommand{\myint}{\bigint}
{\left(B\right)\intop}
\end_inset


\begin_inset Formula 
\[
\myint_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\;\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx
\]

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Note that there is a possibility to add your own math symbol to LyX, but of course you will need to create it in the right format and configure LyX to use it. I don't currently remember how to do it, but I'm sure someone in [LyX's mailing list](http://lists.lyx.org/mailman/listinfo/lyx-users) knows how.

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Phys What exactly does not work? Did you try to open the LyX file I've provided?

Comment: My bad, it was actually working, but I thought it also had to show a bigger integral while editing. Thank you

Comment: @Phys, oh, LyX does nor come an image of a big integral sign, but you can add it to LyX, you just have to create the symbol yourself...